# How I can fix the problem of running flutter app on phone instead of emulator in windows 10

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Hello everyone When I try to run the Flutter app on my phone this problem appears .
any help please?
Thanks

ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\wiam\IdeaProjects\wiamflutter\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not find crash.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.2.1).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/26.2.1/crash-26.2.1.jar
  >   Could not find aapt2-proto.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.3.1).
  >    Searched in the following locations:
  >        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/0.3.1/aapt2-proto-0.3.1.jar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
  Command: C:\Users\wiam\IdeaProjects\wiamflutter\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,The solution is to update Android Studio and Android Software development kit.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your flutter package maybe it will work after this.